# Issue installing Jenking ci on Linux mint

Tags: jenkins, linux-mint

when i try to install jenkins on Linux mint i am getting the following error.

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jenkins : Depends: daemon but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I am not sure how to resolve the dependecy issue with daemon. I have tried to install daemon its not somehting which can be installed. I believe i may have to enable some setting for this daemon to work.

Answer (score 0):

So, did you try to run `apt-get -f install`? It usually works.

It is, of course, possible that Mint has packaged `daemon` under a different name.

Please bear in mind that Jenkins does in no way depend on being installed from a Debian package. Jenkins is a single file (jenkins.war) that you can just download yourself and run `java -jar jenkins.war` to play with it.

When you have played enough and want to get serious, you probably want to install a web server that supports .war files, like Tomcat and use that to host Jenkins. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Containers

Comment: thanks for the response. I did try apt-get -f install but dint work for me.